# BLDC worked, but now always in stall. Hall sensor problem?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I have a Maxon BLDC motor (with Hall sensor, no encoder), controlled using ElectroCraft driver, and Arduino UNO.

The motor used to work just fine, however it stopped working and instead, it clicks and ticks as if it is trying to start but something stops it from moving, and the current rises as if the motor is in stall. (I have set current limit protection, so the motor can't get burned). There is no load on the motor.

The problem started when I started to change the settings in the motor driver, or more precisely, a field called "Hall sensor configuration".

From the datasheet:

> "This setting is an adjustment to align hall sensor states to the motor phase output
> sequence. Each increment of this variable shifts the commutation alignment by 60 electrical degrees."

Basically, you can enter numbers from 0 to 11, and each number makes the motor act differently. From not moving, to clicking, to working perfectly.

At some point the motor worked fine, and then when I kept changing the number to check for a better configuration, the problem started - and when I changed the number back to the one that worked - it doesn't change a thing.

I looked online, and I found an explanation that might explain it, but not exactly: they said that if the hall configuration is wrong, then the motor can put itself into stall (even though it's not in stall), which then makes the current rise, and then burns the motor. And it all makes sense.
However, I doubt that's what happened, because:

1. That's a high quality motor (Maxon), and I had current limit protection, I doubt it dies so easily
2. The motor is still working (sort of)
3. I went through this procedure many times with many motors, and it never caused any problem.

Does anyone have any idea what else can cause this behaviour of the motor?
Clicking and ticking as if it is trying to move but something holds it in place, and the current rises as if it is in stall. Event though there is absolutely no load.

Also, does it really makes sense what I've read about the misconfiguration-stall-burnt?

I will really appreciate any help, any piece of information is priceless.

Thanks in advance!

Ron

Comment: Try the motor with another controller, and the controller with another motor. It may be the motor controller became damaged while the sensor was misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried another motor with the same motor controller and it worked perfect. Then, I tried the problematic motor with another motor controller (Maxon controller) and it still doesn't work. Furthermore, the ElectroCraft software allows me to visually see the Hall sensors feedback - and with the problematic motor, it looks really dodgy, as if there is no logic behind it. Any suggestions?